# DatePicker in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to integrate a date picker component using action script for date of birth.
any avialable components ? please give url's ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Calendar component @ minimalcomps
http://minimalcomps.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [DateField](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/controls_12.html)

```
 var dp:DateField = new DateField();
 dp.yearNavigationEnabled = true; // enables you to move thru years quickly.
 addElement(dp);
```